# Subpart array affects main array by individual replacement, but does not affect main array when vectorized

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why does the subpart array affects main array by individual replacement, but does not affect main array when vectorized?

For example if the code is:

```
import numpy as np

Z =np.array( 
    [[0,4,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0,0],
     [0,1,0,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0]])
print Z

X= Z[1:4,0:3]
X[0][0]=9
print X
print Z  #<=== X affects Z
X=X*3+1
print X
print Z  #<=== X do not affect Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because slicing a Numpy array returns a view of the original array, so modifying it is going to affect the original array as well.

From [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> All arrays generated by basic slicing are always [views](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view) of the original
>   array.

Comment: Would't X=X*3+1 also be modifying the original array?

Comment: @user3211991 No, cause you are creating a new array with the math operations, and assigning it to the var X try with `print id(X)` before and after the line `X=X*3+1`

Comment: @user3211991 X*3 simply returns a new array and then you're pointing `X` to that new array. it is similar to: `a = b= []; b=2;`, this cannot affect `a` in anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`X = X * 3 + 1` doesn't modify the original array because it doesn't modify `X` in-place.

Imagine:

```
Y = X * 3 + 1
```

You wouldn't expect this to change the original array, right? `X = X * 3 + 1` is the same kind of expression. It doesn't change `X` itself, it just changes the value of the local variable `X` to a completely new array.

If you want to modify the original array you can do this:

```
X *= 3
X += 1
```

This will operate on the insides of `X` and therefore change `Z`.

Answer (score 0):

As Ashwini Chaudhary mentioned, slicing a Numpy array returns a **view** of original array, but when you run `X=X*3+1`, X is never a view of Z any more, the reference of X is changed, so even run `X*=3` afterwards doesn't change Z neither